# Having trouble with requiring AWS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to implement DynamoDB in a Javascript file. I tried out multiple tutorials in succession to no avail. All I'm trying to do is make a query from within my Javascript code (which is being run in an HTML page). Unfortunately, my code doesn't even get up to that. It throws me errors when I try to require AWS-SDK. I installed aws-sdk with Node.js. After being confused by multiple tutorials, I ended up with the following code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.2.0/r.js"></script>
<script src="boom.js"></script>
</head>

<body></body>

</html>
```

JavaScript (boom.js):

```
require(['aws-sdk'], function (foo) {

    var CONF = require("./super_secure_conf.json");
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");

    function init(){
        AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
            access_key_id: CONF.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: CONF.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: "us-east-1"
        });
        DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();

    }
});
```

The file "super_secret_conf.json" is a JSON file containing my AWS Credentials. I tried storing the credentials at `~/.aws/credentials` previously, but that wasn't working. (Should `credentials` be a folder or file? I had tried saving my credentials in a blank file – without any extension. Just thought I'd mention.) So I followed another tutorial, which said to use the JSON method (and I am aware that it is very insecure) which is what you see here. I still get an error though:

`Error: Module name "super_secure_conf.json" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

All and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring AWS twice, calling it `foo` the first time. And you aren't waiting for the callback from your config.json require call (or even passing it a callback function). I believe your code needs to change to look like this:

```
require(['aws-sdk', "./super_secure_conf.json"], function (AWS, CONF) {    
    function init(){
        AWS.config = new AWS.Config({
            access_key_id: CONF.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: CONF.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region: "us-east-1"
        });
        DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB();    
    }
});
```

However I'm not sure if the path `"./super_secure_conf.json"` is actually going to work. That looks like a path you would use for loading a file in a server-side NodeJS application, not a browser-side JavaScript application.

Note that the reason you have to load your config this way is because the `~/.aws/credentials` method of loading an AWS config is not going to work for a JavaScript app running in a browser. I think you've been reading NodeJS tutorials which aren't going to translate perfectly to JavaScript in the browser. I would highly recommend you start by looking through the documentation for [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-intro.html), and in particular read the page on [Configuring the SDK in the Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html).

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Your answer solved half the problem, but it still required me to configure the `IdentityPoolId`. Other than that, thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: @Mark B, Probably I should post a new question.While a prepare to post a proper  new question, I ask you here: I Implemented a sample AWS Serverless architecture flow with Dynamodb-Lamda(for DAO )-API Gateway-S3 as website. I want to secure the API. I read the related documentation. Am wanting to Implement IAM Authentication. Presently I am using Javascript SDK. I tried to use ~/.aws/credentials file but could not, your answer above informs me that I cannot use this method. Please tell how to externalize IAM User credentials, and how would the Javascript SDK know to identify my AWS Account.